How to determine the entry point for water for a window leak?
We have a leak that shows up on the center of the window only when there are heavy rains with heavy winds (rain coming in at an angle)
Video of leak and exterior photos: https://imgur.com/a/yM2IVP3
Window on 1st level, same size window right above it on second level. House has brick veneer and build 2021. No leak on the window above it.
Right behind the leak on opposite side a a weep hole between 2 bricks.

Regrettably, finding the source of a water leak is difficult, because the water may travel along a surface (e.g., a beam or insulation) until it leaks out far away. On a dry day, try aiming a water hose at different spots on the exterior, waiting about 10 minutes between changing location, and check for new leaks each time.

Can you provide a picture of the outside top of the window?  It could be leaking at the flashing above the lower window, or coming in the top window someplace and running down.

@SteveSh updated the imgur album with pics from exterior, if you need me to get on a ladder and get more pics I can do it....
I also checked out the sill for the window above and all seems pretty nicely sealed..

I have similar construction on my house - brick veneer.  But I don't think there are any weep holes at the bottom of the brick courses, where they meet the lintel (the heavy piece of iron above the window opening).

What is sealing the large gap between the underside of the lintel and the window frame?

@DelphicOracle and are those 3 big slots in the mortar supposed to be some kind of drainage or weep holes?  Weep holes and that gap you mention don't seem to make any sense together.

@Huesmann The slots are supposed to be there along with a concealed flashing on top of the lintel to divert water penetrating the brick veneer. The symptoms describe a condition where air pressure is driving water into unprotected gaps. The pictures show water penetration above the window frame.

I'm looking up these terms to determin what are you talking in trade speaks, but I also have someone coming over tomorrow to give it a look over, will keep you updated
There is some exterior caulking filling the gap between the frame and lintel underside. a year or two ago when it happened, noticed the caulk was bad and coming out and I recaulked it with exterior caulk

@DelphicOracle but where would the flashing be?

Behind the brick course. Usually it is some kind of reinforced fabric or tarpaper attached to the wall and overlapping the lintel.

@Sarvesh.lad This gap looks pretty deep. I would feel better if a backer rod was installed flush with the exterior face of the window frame and caulking applied to overlap both the window frame and the lintel.

I had folks over this morning and it’s coming from the window above… bad caulking….

Update: The caulking on the window above was just surface caulk, as the house settled it split open or spearated... the window guy shoved caulked inside and then caulked again.... He alse caulked the weep holes above the top window....
He will be back next week after it cures to test it out again and finish payment.
Anyone who cares for estimate: $175 flat with parts with $30 in DFW Metroplex.

UPDATE 2: Well the window guy caulked and went after doing his own test.
Today it rained aggressively again and now he suspect it is the roof and recommended we call a roofer
